# How to Pass Multiple Objects to Resful Service as Form Parameter using Jquery

Tags: java, jquery, rest, post, hql

So I have two classes

Restaurant

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "resturant")
public class Restaurant {
private int id;
private String name;
private String Location;

private int rating;

private float longitude;

private float latitude;

public Restaurant(String name, String location, int rating, float longi,
        float lati) {
    this.name = name;
    this.Location = location;
    this.rating = rating;
    this.longitude = longi;
    this.latitude = lati;
}

public Restaurant() {

}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@Column(name = "id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "Name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name = "Location")
public String getLocation() {
    return Location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    Location = location;
}

@Column(name = "rating")
public int getRating() {
    return rating;
}

public void setRating(int rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

@Column(name = "longitutde")
public float getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

@Column(name = "latitude")
public float getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

}
```

and 
Type

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "type")
public class Type {
private int id;
private String name;

public Type() {

}

public Type(String name) {
    this.name = name;

}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@Column(name = "id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

Now i have a third Class that take object of both these class as foreign key

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant_detail")
public class RestaurantDetails {

private transient Restaurant restaurant;
private transient Type type;
private int id;


public RestaurantDetails() {

}
public RestaurantDetails(Restaurant r , Type t){
    this.restaurant=r;
    this.type=t;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id")
public Restaurant getRestaurant() {
    return restaurant;
}
public void setRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
    this.restaurant = restaurant;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_type")
public Type getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(Type type) {
    this.type = type;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@Column(name = "id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}



}
```

Now i have setup a restful service that adds Restaurant to the database

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void addRestaurant(@FormParam("name") String name,
        @FormParam("location") String location,
        @FormParam("longitutde") float longi,
        @FormParam("latitude") float lati, @FormParam("rating") int rating) {
    Restaurant r = new Restaurant(name, location, rating, longi, lati);
    RestaurantBO rBo = new RestaurantBO();
    rBo.addRestaurant(r);

}
```

and one to add restaurant Details

```
    @Path("/restaurantDetail")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void addRestaurantDetail(@FormParam("restaurant") Restaurant restaurant,
        @FormParam("type") Type type) {
    RestaurantDetails r = new RestaurantDetails(restaurant,type);
    RestaurantBO rBo = new RestaurantBO();
    rBo.addRestaurantDetails(r);

}
```

Now i have no problem passing the parameters to add restaurant class of the restful service

But i am having confusions about the restaurant detail class. How do i pass 2 class objects as parameter to the service. How do i construct that JSON to pass the data or form parameters

i am using this simple way to call the service

```
$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "http://localhost:8080/Appetizers_project/rest/restuarant",
        data : data,
        success : function() {

            alert();
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("ERROR Occured");
        },
        dataType : "text"
    });
```

Comment: Well i found a simple walk around , Not the best solution
But basically i just added the code to add resturant detail in the add restuarant part of the rest service since i get all the details passed to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the @consume to Application_Json and directly read a RestaurantDetails object

```
@Path("/restaurantDetail")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void addRestaurantDetail(RestaurantDetails restDet) {

    rBo.addRestaurantDetails(restDet);

}
```

In the client side use the JSON.stringify library

```
data = {
   restaurant:{
      //rest props
   },
   type: {
      //type props
   },
};

$.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "http://localhost:8080/Appetizers_project/rest/restuarant",
        data : JSON.stringify(data),
        success : function() {

            alert();
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("ERROR Occured");
        },
        dataType : "json"
    });
```